# MSBUild script to read VCS settings

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

Using MSBuild script, can I read my VCS root settings?
Suppose I have two VCS settings for my TeamCity Build Configuration.
1. VCS Root Name is VCSId1 and Root is $/Source/Dev/Project1
2. VCS Root Name is VCSId2 and Root is $/Source/Dev/Project2

Can i read VCSId1 and its root using MSBuild script?

Comment: I tried $(teamcity_build_vcs_branch_VCSId1 ). But this is returning null value.

Comment: Do you need absolute path from TC build agent or just relative path which you specified in VCS settings?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pavel Bakshy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pavel Bakshy. There are two VCS roots. Type Of VCS is Team Foundation Server. The 'VCS root name' of first VCS root is VCSId1 and its 'Root' is '$/Source/Dev/Project1'. The 'VCS root name' of second VCS root is VCSId2 and its 'Root' is '$/Source/Dev/Project2'.  By giving VCS root name, can i get the value entered for Root field. ie by giving VCSId1, can i get '$/Source/Dev/Project1' using MSBuild script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom build parameter like described [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Parameters#ConfiguringBuildParameters-ConfigurationParameters). For example `MyRoot1` with value `$/Source/Dev/Project1`, then you can use it in VCS settings, specifying `%MyRoot1%` in Root field.

To pass it to you msbuild script you can write `/p:Root=%MyRoot1%` in `Command line parameters:` field from MsBuild Build step. After that it could be accessable in msbuild script as `$(Root)` property.